# How to Remove Adhesive Residue from New Wooden Table?

Tags: cleaning

I recently purchased and received a brand new black wooden coffee table which arrived with a sticker on top. I carefully removed the sticker itself but it left a adhesive or sticky residue. What can I use to remove this residue without leaving a mark or blemish on the coffee table? 
Thank you

Answer (score 3):

- Goo Gone. Used this many times, never had an issue.
- WD-40 and elbow grease. Emphasis on elbow grease, works in a pinch though. Be cautious about using WD-40 on wood though.
- Rubbing alcohol. Supposed to take care of most every type of adhesive, and in my opinion, it smells nice.
- 3M Adhesive Remover. Never used this stuff, but I hear it's amazing.
- Baby Oil(Thanks to @CarlWitthoft). He says it works well.
- A razor blade and a steady hand. I'd consider this a last resort.

Comment: I'd be very hesitant to use WD40 on a wood surface.  Even more hesitant to use a razor-- you're pretty much guaranteed to remove the finish.  GooGone, or baby oil (yeah, really!) are the choices to use.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Amended my answer to reflect those points. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please grab a hair dryer, warm the surface of the adhesive them gently rub the adhesive off with a stiff cloth with a little cooking oil on it. It will come off easy with no issues.